# Handling audio file intent in react native

Tags: android, react-native

Can somebody help me in receiving audio file intent in react-native,
I want when android user share a call recording file(.amr) with my react-native app i can access that file and store to a remote server (for monitoring quality),

till now am able to make my app available to share audio file with adding below code in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

I have searched on Internet for my problem there are some blogs that handling Text/url intent with below code in MainActivity.java

```
 @Override
    protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
        return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
            @Override
            protected Bundle getLaunchOptions() {
                Intent intent = MainActivity.this.getIntent();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("url", intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT));

                return bundle;
            }
        };
    }
```

its working file with text intent and i am able to get the shared url in my initialProps

```
e.g {"url":"https://xxxxxx.com/abc"}
```

but when i am using same above code with audio/.amr file intent i am getting null  `e.g {"url":null}`,

I believe if I got the file name or its full path in my initial props then i can get that file after using **react-native-fs**

i am new in java and native part of android,
it would be great help if someone can guide me the right way of doing above task.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You should use EXTRA_STREAM  for audio. I have been searching for same thing, including to receive other documents too(pdf, doc, audio etc). I didn't find any wrapper that do same for all formats I require to receive. You can create your own through this for audio or whatever type you want https://www.bennettnotes.com/react-native-android-receive-data-from-share-intent/ Hope this helps.

```
@Override
    protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        protected Bundle getLaunchOptions() {
            Intent intent = MainActivity.this.getIntent();
            String type=intent.getType();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle=null;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    type.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           if(type.startsWith("text/"))
               bundle.putString("url", intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT));
           else {
                Uri uri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
                if(uri!=null)
               { bundle.putString("url", uri.getPath());}
           }
            return bundle;
        }
    };
}
```